# Scan the web container folder for files

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

Hi I need a folder called policy in web folder and in that folder there will be a files listed I need to scan that policy folder for files and accordingly I need to take take further steps.
Here is my project structure:
[image: project structure with policy folder and a file in the policy folder]

My question is I need to scan the policy folder in my controller and get the file names.
How can I do that in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[File.listFiles()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29) will give you the list of files.

```
File folder = new File(path); // path is your folder path.
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(); 

   for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
      if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) { 
          //do your stuff
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

To scan a folder and obtain the names use method listFiles in class File. Example:

```
File directory = new File("your-policy-directory");
String[] names = directory.listFiles();

for(int i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
    //do something...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a parameter in one of your properties files to set the absolute path of the directory to update it easyly. Then read this parameter in your controller and use `java.io.File.listFiles()` to retrieve the corresponding list of files.

Answer (score 0):

I did it in this way: as mentioned in above answers:

```
String realPath = getServlet().getServletContext().getRealPath(File.separator);
        File folder = new File(realPath+"\\policy"); // path is your folder path.
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(); 
           for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
              if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) { 
                  //Do stuff
              }
           }
```